# Set font weight of \textbf

Tags: fonts, bold, sans-serif

I am using Source Sans Pro as my main sans serif font, like so:

`\usepackage[semibold]{sourcesanspro}`

Using the semibold option works as intended, but it affects all other fonts as well. When I later use another font that does not have semibold characters (case in point: Gentium), supposedly "bold" text is shown plain. If, however, I simply use

`\usepackage{sourcesanspro}`

everything works fine. How can I restore `\textbf{}` to use real bold again for all fonts other than Source Sans?

MWE added:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,headings=big]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,microtype,leading} 

\usepackage[oldstyle,semibold]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{gentium}

\raggedbottom
\leading{14pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Look at my semi-bold title!}
\lipsum[1]

Oh, no, \textbf{this} should be bold!

\end{document}
```

Yes, I do get a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/gentium/sb/n' undefined(Font)
using `T1/gentium/m/n' instead on input line 21.
```

I'd rather LaTeX used the bold variant in this case.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  This package loads `mweights.sty` exactly to avoid such a problem.

Comment: MWE added, I hope this makes it a little clearer.

Comment: I think you have an old style file, try updating to `sourcesanspro [2013/09/23]` - then the `gentium` will be attempted to be loaded at `bx` but on my system it does find that and substitues with `b` - which is still bold.

Comment: Who would've thought it? Seems there was an issue with [2013/04/26]. Using [2013/09/23] now and everything is working as expected. Thank you! If you'd like to provide that as an answer, I'll be happy to make it the official one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version `[2013/09/23]` of `sourcesanspro.sty` loads the `mweights.sty` to exactly cope with such issues.  `mweights.sty` provides means for specifying e.g. different bold weights for roman, typewriter and sans serif fonts.  Compiling your code with this newer package gives:

[image: Sample output]

Note that the log contains the information

> ```
> LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/gentium/bx/n' in size <12> not available
> (Font)              Font shape `T1/gentium/b/n' tried instead on input line 22.
> ```

Showing that an attempt has been made to load it at weight `bx`, but this was not found and `b` was used instead.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, the outdated file really was the culprit ...